# Salesforce REST API Query More than 2000

Tags: java, rest, pagination, salesforce

I'm trying to execute a [SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_soql.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_calls_soql.htm|SkinName=webhelp) query using [salesforce REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm) which will return 2,749 results. However it seems there is a limit of 2,000 results that can be returned for a given request.

Is there a way to query the remaining 749 results without using the OFFSET keyword? (it's not currently supported in my production environment).

I looked into this and found a [queryMore](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_querymore.htm) function but I can't find a way to call it through the REST API.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

part of the result is a nextRecordsUrl property which when you do a GET on it, will return you the next chunk of the results. See the section on [query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm) in the rest api docs.

Comment: Ah, I feel dumb, I was not looking at the actual response that was coming back, just manipulating it in code. Thanks so much.